# how can I add rows to DB on android only when DB is created? (using room)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I have category class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Categories",indices = {@Index(value = {"id"},
        unique = true)})
public class Category  implements Serializable {

    public  Category(String name,int icon,int color)
    {
        _name= name;
        _icon = icon;
        _color = color;
    }
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String _name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "icon")
    public int _icon;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "color")
    public int _color;

    public String get_name() {return _name;}

    public int getColor() {
        return _color;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return _icon;
    }
}
```

and I would like to create constant rows only when DB is newly created and not each time the application is loading.
what I did till now is:

```
protected CategorySingletone() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.

        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(MainActivity.get().getApplicationContext());
        if (db.categoryDao().countCategories()==0) {
            _categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
            _categoryList.add(new Category("Cars", R.drawable.couch, 3));
            _categoryList.add(new Category("Tech", R.drawable.phone, 3));
            _categoryList.add(new Category("Home", R.drawable.book_1, 3));
            _categoryList.add(new Category("Leisure", R.drawable.book_1, 3));
            _categoryList.add(new Category("Motors", R.drawable.book_4, 3));
            _categoryList.add(new Category("Fashion", R.drawable.book_5, 3));
            for (Iterator<Category> i = _categoryList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                Category item = i.next();
                db.categoryDao().insertAll(item);
            }
        }
```

while I am checking if rows exists. 
is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would be to use the [`DatabaseUtils` **`queryNumEntries`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

e.g.

```
    if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"Categories") == 0) {
        .......
    }
```

Comment: when do you think it is the correct time to call it?

Comment: Also, I am using Romm database so I dont have SQLDatabase object